# Django. Accessing additional user field

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a form, so user could upload an avatar to his profile.
I've got a class which looks like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    picture = models.FileField(upload_to='media/images', blank=True, null=True)
```

and now I want to access the field `picture` in my views, so I can put some picture in it.
I'm trying to do it like so:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        userForm = SignupForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        profileForm = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if userForm.is_valid():
            ...
            user.profile.picture = request.POST['picture']
                    ...
            profileForm.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
                    ...
```

and then pass it to the template.
I read somewhere that I can acceess such field through the `related_name` specified in models, so that's what I tried.
But when I'm trying to upload the picture it says: `User has no profile.`

Also I read about `get_profile()` function a lot, but as I understood it's depricatred now.

So, will, you please tell me how can I access this field?
May be I'm doing it all wrong? If yes then what is the right way of doing such things?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a step here. You need to check that *both* the user and the profile forms are valid. Then, you need to save the user form to get a User object. Then you need to create the profile object, associate it with the user, and save it.

I don't know why you're setting the profile picture separately - surely it should be part of the Profile form, and will be saved alongside it.

Comment: Thank you for response!
I added validation for both forms.
Can you please give an example on how can I create the profile object?

When you are talking about separate profile picture you mean 2 models? I guess I don't need it, but I don't know how can I extend the default User model the other way..

Answer (score 0):

Here's where I think you're getting confused:

```
 userForm = SignupForm(request.POST, instance=user)
 profileForm = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

You're using two different forms at the same time, but only validating the first:

```
if userForm.is_valid():
```

And what you're getting is a `User has no profile.` because, while the user exists, the profile does not (not before running the `profileForm.save()` anyway). Remember, those are two different models. And even then, you're also doing it wrong for two reasons:

- picture will reside in `request.FILES` and not `request.POST` because it is, well, a file
- you're trying to assign the picture to `user.profile.picture` - but that makes no sense, because you should assign it to the profile and then link that profile to the user (remember, user is a field on the Profile model). And of course, if picture is part of the form you don't need to do this anyway

So, essentially, this:

```
profileForm = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
profileForm.instance.user = request.user #link the profile to current user
if profileForm.is_valid():
    profileForm.save() #now you have a profile
```

Comment: Thank you for response!
So, I did what you advised. Now "print(profileForm.instance.user)" returns current user, but when I'm trying to save the profileForm it says: "column user_id is not unique".

As I understood about saving the picture it should be like this: "user.profile.picture = request.FILES['picture']" and isn't it supposed to be executed before saving profileForm?

Well.. I'm really confused about what to do next :\ 
Is there a way I can do all this things within just one model?

Comment: if the profile already exists, you need to use the `instance` argument in your call to the form: `ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=...)`. You can use some conditions to figure out if the user has a related profile object or not